# trying to send textarea.value to discord embed not working

Tags: javascript, html, discord

My HTML and JS script are here. The message that you get from the first textarea works but not from the text that is actually in the Modal. I am trying to use the text that is typed into the textarea by using .value, is this right? Yes, this is in a html thing and all that stuff, it is unnecessary to include that though.

```
<label for="contentWebhook1">Type here what you would like to send as the message (not in modal)</label>
    <br>
    <textarea id="contentElement" name="contentWebhook1" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea> // this works fine
    <br>
    <label for="titleContent2"> This is the title of the modal</label>
    <br>
    <textarea id="contentTitle" name="titleContent2" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
    <br>
    <label for="contentDescription">Description</label>
    <br>

    <textarea name="contentDescription" id="contentDescriptionWebhook" cols="50" rows="3"></textarea>
    <button onclick="sendMessage()">Send message </button>
    <script>

        const messageContent = document.getElementById('contentElement');
        const messageTitle = document.getElementById('contentTitle');
        const descriptionTitle = document.getElementById('contentDescriptionWebhook');

            function sendMessage() {

            const request = new XMLHttpRequest;
             request.open("POST", "my link here, does work");
             request.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');

              const params = {
                username: "",
                avatar_url: "",
                content: messageContent.value,
                embeds: [ myEmbed ]
             }

              request.send(JSON.stringify(params));
          }

          function hexToDecimal(hex) {
            return parseInt(hex.replace("#", ""), 16)
           }
        
            var myEmbed= {
                author: {
                name: ""
            },

            title: messageTitle.value,
            description:descriptionTitle.value, // This goes inside modal under title ^
            color: hexToDecimal("#2e5883") // This is color
        }
```

Comment: you should get the elements inside the handler to make sure they get an up-to-date value

Comment: Make sure that you are calling .value after you have typed something. Don't run code at the start that will use empty textarea value. For instance that at the bottom is not inside a function.